# Chain 2 futures - calculate one and return another

Tags: multithreading, scala, future

I have a `Future` and a function which I want to execute once the `Future` is completed. And return a new `Future`.

I want to create a function doing that but I can't:

```
def chain(fut: Future[A], continueFun: Future[A] => B): Future[B] = future {
  fut onComplete {  case Success(x) => continueFun(x) }  // ops, Unit  
}
```

I omitted `onFailure` for simplicity.

However, `onComplete`, onSuccess and onFailure - they all return `Unit`. How do I return `Future[B]` once `Future[A]` is completed?

Comment: is it important that `continueFun` takes a Future as argument? otherwise I think you could simply do `futureA.map(continueFun)`

Comment: @tehlexx, yes, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue is a bit more complex, you can however `flatMap` and `map`. The `join` behaviour is already defined.

```
for {
   a <- someFuture
   b <- someOtherFuture
} yield {
   a + b // or whatever goes here
}
```

You can even sequence:

```
for {
   resultOfFuture <- someFuture
   nextResult <- getResult(resultOfFuture) // chaining them 
} yield {
   // etc
}


 def chain[A, B](fut: Future[A], continueFun: Future[A] => B): Future[B] = {
    for {
      a <- fut
    } yield {
      continueFun(fut)
    }
  }
```

Comment: how is it applicable to my `chain`?

Comment: if it isn't, why did you give me that as an answer?

Comment: The solution I need is not necessarily should be simpler, it  should only be applicable to my question and nothing else.

Comment: That's what I need. Does "for" in that case become "map" or "flatMap" by compiler (since "for" is a syntactic sugar for them and foreach also)?

Comment: it seems we calculate the value of `fut` which is `a` for no reason?

Comment: `continueFun(fut)` returns B, whereas chain should return Future[B]. You wanted to wrap it into future { }.

Answer (score 1):

A promise can be used to chain futures.

```
def chain[A, B](fut: Future[A], continueFun: Future[A] => B): Future[B] = {

  val p = Promise[B]()  // A promise that will be completed after fut completes.

  fut onComplete {  case Success(x) => p success continueFun(fut) 
                    case Failure(ex) => p failure ex } 

  p.future // this future will be completed by the promise, which in turn will be completed by fut.

}
```

Comment: I was thinking of Promise also.